# Run a batch file ignoring the variables in the file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was hoping you could help, i'm trying to run a batch file with a very long name, how can i set it so that it finds only part of the file and runs that, for example, if my file name is 111222333444555666-mycompuetrname.bat what command can i use so i can just put in the batch file mycomputername.bat (i cant just use *.bat as there are other older batch files within the same folder)

The first part of the file name is not constant and it changes but my computer name always stays the same.

So basically i need a batch file to run another batch file which get its file name changed everyday except for the computer name part. I need it to ignore the parts of the file name that keep changing.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Omid

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming, there is only one of them:

```
for %%i in (*mycomputername.bat) do %%i
```

if there are more, this will run the first one found, but you could run all of them with `do call %%i`.

To run the last of several, use `dir` to sort accordingly :

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /o-d *mycomputername.bat') do %%i
```

`/o-d` sorts **by date**, newest first; to sort **by filename**, use `/o-n` .See `dir /?` for details

Comment: Hi, this is brilliant, and it works but it runs the oldest batch file in that folder, is there a way of getting it to run the latest batch file? for example, these are some of the batch files: 2014.11.05-01.11.27-OSTSSPATP01-40499011-HOSTNAME  and 2014.11.27-03.56.33-OSTSSPATP01-44017109-HOSTNAME and 2015.04.02-06.21.15-OSTSSPATP01-54015660-HOSTNAME  i would therefore would like it to run the file that starts with 2015 as that is the latest one.

Comment: yes, it is. The syntax is a bit more complex, but not much. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for this, it now picks up the latest batch file but i dont think its running it and when i do it through telnet which is what i need to run it through it closes my telnet session. It did work on one machine when i ran it while on the actual machine and not using remote telnet but on another machine it didnt even work when ran locally. this is the code im using, for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /o-d *%hostname%.bat') do %%i ive had to use %hostname% as that changes when i do it on different machines. Think i may just need to tinker with it more, but so far perfect :) and thank you

Answer (score -2):

If you are on unix/linux, it can be done with the following:

```html
find . -name *mycompuetrname.sh | exec sh $0
```

If you have to do this on Windows, you will have to find equivalent of the above commands.

Comment: The tags make it abundantly clear that this is a Windows question.